# Beginner python error - no attribute found

Tags: python, class, attributes

I have this class bgp_route:

```
class bgp_route:
    def _init_(self, path):
        self.nextHop = None
        self.asPath = ''
        self.asPathLength = 0
        self.routePrefix = None
```

However, when I run the following test code;

```
from bgp_route import bgp_route

testRoute =  bgp_route()

testRoute.asPath += 'blah'
print testRoute.asPath
```

I get the following error:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "testbgpRoute.py", line 6, in <module>
        testRoute.asPath += 'blah'
    AttributeError: bgp_route instance has no attribute 'asPath'
```

What is the cause of this error? 
Shouldn't the instantiate of bgp_route have initialized the attribute asPath to the empty string?

Comment: You need `__init__` not `_init_`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You misspelled `__init__`:

```
def _init_(self, path):
```

You need **two** underscores on both ends. By not using the correct name, Python never calls it and the `self.asPath` attribute assignment is never executed.

Note that the method expects a `path` argument however; you'll need to specify that argument when constructing your instance. Since your `__init__` method otherwise *ignores* this argument, you probably want to remove it:

```
class bgp_route:
    def __init__(self):
        self.nextHop = None
        self.asPath = ''
        self.asPathLength = 0
        self.routePrefix = None
```

Comment: probably should add object also

Comment: @PadraicCunningham not sure if introducing that concept is helpful at this juncture.

Answer (score 1):

It's called `__init__`, with two underscores on both side, like any other python magic method.

And BTW, your constructor expects a `path` argument.