# Python error no attribute found

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, machine-learning

Am working on machine learning project so 
When I import the text file which is a table of values where no columns titles when I wrote this :

```
import numpy 
Data = numpy.genfromtext( « test.txt » , delimiter=none)
Data[0:4]
```

Shows error no attribute is found

Comment: I think you mean [`numpy.genfromtxt()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html). genfrom**txt** not genfrom**text**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [numpy genfromtxt issues in Python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581070/numpy-genfromtxt-issues-in-python3)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Beginner python error - no attribute found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27646226/beginner-python-error-no-attribute-found)